# Remove comma on last element in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array like ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"] and what to render to the browser a comma after each one EXCEPT the last one in jquery/JS, how do I do that with the function below? Right now, it adds a comma to all elements in the array that includes the last one, and I don't want it on the last one.

JS

```
  if(designations) {
        var newLinks = designations.map(function(agentDesignations){
            agentDesignations = agentDesignations.toLowerCase();
            return '<a class = "designation-box" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#' + agentDesignations + '-modal" data-value = '+ agentDesignations + '>' + agentDesignations + '</a>' + ',\n'});
        return newLinks.join("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shold you solve by using regex `+$`

```
return newLinks.join("\n").replace(/,+$/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the ",\n" from the return in the map, and change the last return to `newLinks.join(",\n\n")`

like this:

```
  if(designations) {
        var newLinks = designations.map(function(agentDesignations){
            agentDesignations = agentDesignations.toLowerCase();
            return '<a class = "designation-box" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#' + agentDesignations + '-modal" data-value = '+ agentDesignations + '>' + agentDesignations + '</a>';
        });
        return newLinks.join(",\n\n") + '\n';
    }
```

there's two "\n" in the join, because that's what you'd end up with currently

more concisely, I'd code this as follows:

```
  if(designations) {
        return designations.map(function(agentDesignations){
            agentDesignations = agentDesignations.toLowerCase();
            return '<a class = "designation-box" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#' + agentDesignations + '-modal" data-value = '+ agentDesignations + '>' + agentDesignations + '</a>';
        }).join(",\n\n") + '\n';
    }
```

note: two \n's vs one \n's have make no difference on the rendering of the resulting HTML, so the last line can simply be

```
}).join(",\n") + '\n';
```

or even

```
}).join(", "); //  note the SPACE, it does make a difference
```